# Can I hide remove icon only for some files in antd Upload component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I want to hide remove button in [Antd](https://ant.design/components/upload/) Upload component only for files that meet certain criteria. I know remove icon can be disabled for every file using `showRemoveIcon` prop. But how can I do this for an individual file in the `fileList`

Comment: you can have your own node as a children props in <upload>{children}</upload> and handle the icons there, map your fileList and manage the remove icons by uid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @FatemehQasemkhani . BTW do you have and example link which I can refer to. Tried to implement it myself but not able  figure out how.

Comment: I have not seen your scenario before, I hope my answer help you. @Johnson Cherian

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported by antd currently.  There is no support for per-file custom icons.  I am having this same problem and submitted it as a feature request for ant-design at https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/26682

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
handleRemoveId = id => {
    if(id === '-1') {
      return null;
    } else {
      return (
        <DeleteOutlined />
      )
    }
}

const uploadButton = (
 <div>
    <PlusOutlined />
    <div className="ant-upload-text">Upload</div>
 </div>
);

<Upload
  action="https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76"
  listType="picture-card"
  onPreview={this.handlePreview}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
>
  <div>
    {fileList.length && fileList.map(item => (
        <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
          <img src={item.url} alt="" height={80} />
          <span style={{ position: "absolute", left: '50%', top: '50%', transform: 'translate(-50%,-50%)', color: '#fff' }}>
            {this.handleRemoveId(item.uid)}
            <EyeOutlined />
           </span>
        </div>
     ))}
     {fileList.length < 8 ? uploadButton : null}
  </div>
</Upload>
```

You should handle all remove and visit by yourself, and add css alot, and check the remove icon by related uid you mean.

**Note**: It can write more better, Just was a hint and I dont know about your exact scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this approach to hide the preview and delete icons on image

```
.ant-upload-list-item-actions {
  display: none;
}
```